# Creating subquery in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I convert the following SQL query into Laravel query builder?

```
select
    *
from
    users
where
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    from
        posts
    where
        posts.created_by = users.id )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select('*')
            ->from('posts')
            ->whereRaw('posts.created_by = users.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

You can also take a look at the [documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-exists-clauses)

Comment: What do you mean? This will retrieve all users that have a record (or more) in posts.

Comment: Also as you can see from [this example](https://implode.io/yrvfjT), it outputs the query you need :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting/marking it as the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Why use `whereRaw` instead of `->where('posts.created_by', '=', 'users.id')` ?

Comment: Both would work. However `whereRaw()` can be *slightly* faster in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `has` method with the corresponding relationship.

To do this:

1. Create `User` and `Post` models.
2. Define the relationships between the models, e.g. `User` has many `Post` with `posts` as relationship and `Post` belongs to `User`.
3. Use the relationship with `has` method like this: `User::has('posts')->get()` where `posts` is the name of the relationship in `User` model.

---

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships):

> When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, imagine you want to retrieve all blog posts that have at least one comment. To do so, you may pass the name of the relationship to the has and  orHas methods:

```
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments')->get();
```

So in your code, it will retrieve all users that have at least one post